# How To Publish SSIS Project/Package on Server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have created an SSIS package in SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio on my local machine and now I **want to share that package with the client**.and also **want to deploy that package on Server**

so I am searching for the solution how to share that package with the client.

if you guys know how to share SSIS PACKAGE please provide the solution...

Comment: What do you mean by share? Like give/deploy the package? You could just send them the .dtsx file found in the project folder

Comment: hello @ppijnenburg, yes, I want to give/deploy that package to a client....thanks for the solution...so just by sharing the .dtsx file he gets that package?

Comment: @ppijnenburg its not working.....

Comment: If you want the client to have the source and be able to update/debug the package inside Visual Studio you can just give him the DTSX. Otherwies you can deploy your package to SQL Server via Visual studio, or build the solution and share the ispac file wich can be deployed on a remote server.

Comment: What is not working? The sharing itself shouldn't be that hard. Being able to make a package that works in a different enviorment can be a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the package to the SQL Server, you have two options:

1. In Visual Studio; open the solution; right click on the project and select Deploy. Follow the steps in the wizard.
2. In Windows; press Windows + R to bring up the Run window; type in isdeploymentwizard.exe. Follow the steps in the wizard.

As for sharing the SSIS solution, send the client the entire folder that the solution is contained in. I avoid sharing *.dtsx files.